# Boost.Python + opencv Error, Windows 10 x64, "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost

I am a beginner in C++ and python. I have installed boost-1.78.0, OPENCV-4.5.5 and added a new Dynamic-Link Library (DLL) project in Visual Studio 2019, and then successfully build the sln and generated `testSqaure.dll`.

My code is as follows:

```cpp
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include "pch.h"
#include<boost/python.hpp>
#include<boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
using boost::python::list;
using boost::python::numpy::ndarray;
using boost::python::object;
using boost::python::extract;
using std::vector;
using std::array;
using std::sqrt;
using std::min;
using cv::Point2f;
using cv::Point;
using cv::pointPolygonTest;


vector<double> ndarray2vec(const ndarray& arr)
{
    int input_size = static_cast<int>(arr.shape(0));
    double* input_ptr = reinterpret_cast<double*>(arr.get_data());
    vector<double> v_arr(input_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < input_size; ++i)
    {
        v_arr[i] = *(input_ptr + i);
    }
    return v_arr;
}


bool two_line_segment_test(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    if (((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)) == 0) return false;
    const double px = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4));
    const double py = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4));
    if ((((x1 <= px) && (px <= x2)) || ((x2 <= px) && (px <= x1))) && (((x3 <= px) && (px <= x4)) || ((x4 <= px) && (px <= x3))) && (((y1 <= py) && (py <= y2)) || ((y2 <= py) && (py <= y1))) && (((y3 <= py) && (py <= y4)) || ((y4 <= py) && (py <= y3))))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}


object two_triangle_test(ndarray& tri1_side1, ndarray& tri1_side2, ndarray& tri1_side3, ndarray& tri2_side1, ndarray& tri2_side2, ndarray& tri2_side3)
{
    vector<double> v_tri1_side1 = ndarray2vec(tri1_side1),
        v_tri1_side2 = ndarray2vec(tri1_side2),
        v_tri1_side3 = ndarray2vec(tri1_side3),
        v_tri2_side1 = ndarray2vec(tri2_side1),
        v_tri2_side2 = ndarray2vec(tri2_side2),
        v_tri2_side3 = ndarray2vec(tri2_side3);
    array<vector<double>, 3> v_tri1_sides = { v_tri1_side1, v_tri1_side2, v_tri1_side3 };
    array<vector<double>, 3> v_tri2_sides = { v_tri2_side1, v_tri2_side2, v_tri2_side3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            if (two_line_segment_test(v_tri1_sides[i][0], v_tri1_sides[i][1], v_tri1_sides[i][2], v_tri1_sides[i][3], v_tri2_sides[j][0], v_tri2_sides[j][1], v_tri2_sides[j][2], v_tri2_sides[j][3]))
            {
                return object(true);
            }
        }
    }

    vector<Point2f> tri1(3);
    tri1[0] = Point(v_tri1_side1[0], v_tri1_side1[1]);
    tri1[1] = Point(v_tri1_side1[2], v_tri1_side1[3]);
    tri1[2] = Point(v_tri1_side2[2], v_tri1_side2[3]);
    for (auto& side : v_tri2_sides)
    {
        const int retval = static_cast<int>(pointPolygonTest(tri1, Point(side[0], side[1]), false));
        if (retval == 1 || retval == 0) return object(true);
    }
    vector<Point2f> tri2(3);
    tri2[0] = Point(v_tri2_side1[0], v_tri2_side1[1]);
    tri2[1] = Point(v_tri2_side1[2], v_tri2_side1[3]);
    tri2[2] = Point(v_tri2_side2[2], v_tri2_side2[3]);
    for (auto& side : v_tri1_sides)
    {
        const int retval = static_cast<int>(pointPolygonTest(tri2, Point(side[0], side[1]), false));
        if (retval == 1 || retval == 0) return object(true);
    }
    return object(false);
}

array<double, 2> get_foot_point(const vector<double>& v_point, const vector<double>& v_line_p1, const vector<double>& v_line_p2)
{
    const double k = -((v_line_p1[0] - v_point[0]) * (v_line_p2[0] - v_line_p1[0]) + (v_line_p1[1] - v_point[0]) * (v_line_p2[1] - v_line_p1[1]) + 0) / ((v_line_p2[0] - v_line_p1[0]) * (v_line_p2[0] - v_line_p1[0]) + (v_line_p2[1] - v_line_p1[1]) * (v_line_p2[1] - v_line_p1[1]) + 0) * 1.0;


    const double xn = k * (v_line_p2[0] - v_line_p1[0]) + v_line_p1[0];
    const double yn = k * (v_line_p2[1] - v_line_p1[1]) + v_line_p1[1];

    return array<double, 2>{xn, yn};
}


double get_dis_point2line(const vector<double>& v_point, const vector<double>& v_line_p1, const vector<double>& v_line_p2)
{
    array<double, 2> footP = get_foot_point(v_point, v_line_p1, v_line_p2);
    double dist = 0;
    if (((footP[0] - v_line_p1[0]) > 0) ^ ((footP[0] - v_line_p2[0]) > 0))
    {
        dist = sqrt((footP[0] - v_point[0]) * (footP[0] - v_point[0]) + (footP[1] - v_point[1]) * (footP[1] - v_point[1]));
    }
    else
    {
        dist = min(sqrt((v_line_p1[0] - v_point[0]) * (v_line_p1[0] - v_point[0]) + (v_line_p1[1] - v_point[1]) * (v_line_p1[1] - v_point[1])),
            sqrt((v_line_p2[0] - v_point[0]) * (v_line_p2[0] - v_point[0]) + (v_line_p2[1] - v_point[1]) * (v_line_p2[1] - v_point[1])));
    }
    return dist;
}

object circle_triangle_test(const ndarray& center, const object& radius, const ndarray& tri_side1, const ndarray& tri_side2, const ndarray& tri_side3)
{
    const double val_radius = extract<double>(radius);
    vector<double> v_tri_side1 = ndarray2vec(tri_side1),
        v_tri_side2 = ndarray2vec(tri_side2),
        v_tri_side3 = ndarray2vec(tri_side3),
        v_center = ndarray2vec(center);
    array<vector<double>, 3> v_tri_sides = { v_tri_side1, v_tri_side2, v_tri_side3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (sqrt((v_tri_sides[i][0] - v_center[0]) * (v_tri_sides[i][0] - v_center[0]) + (v_tri_sides[i][1] - v_center[1]) * (v_tri_sides[i][1] - v_center[1])) <= val_radius)
        {
            return object(true);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (get_dis_point2line(v_center, { v_tri_sides[i][0], v_tri_sides[i][1] }, { v_tri_sides[i][2], v_tri_sides[i][3] }) <= val_radius)
        {
            return object(true);
        }
    }
    return object(false);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(testSquare)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("two_triangle_test", two_triangle_test);
    def("circle_triangle_test", circle_triangle_test);
}
```

This file mainly writes two functions, which are used to detect whether two triangles overlap, and whether a circle overlaps another triangle.

**But when I rename `testSquare.dll` to `testSquare.pyd` and import it in a .py file, I found that there is a error: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."**

The DLL file generated by boost example.cpp like this can be imported and used correctly:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include<boost/python.hpp>
using boost::python::list;

list Square(list& data)
{
    list ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < len(data); ++i)
    {
        ret.append(data[i] * data[i]);
    }

    return ret;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(testSquare)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("Square", Square);
}
```

Comment: Are the OpenCV DLLs reachable (somewhere in PATH, or the same dir as the .pyd)?

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, `..\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin` has been added to the system environment variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by moving `boost_python37-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78.dll` and `boost_numpy37-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78.dll` to the project folder, or by putting the paths like `D:\Data\dev\boost_1_78_0\stage\lib` where they are in PATH.

The routine for configuring boost doesn't tell me to put this path into PATH.